# 3 conditions with and does not work

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am new to mongodb:

I have a db contains some documents as follow:

```
/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("546ea531d38ed4b9eaaa46eb"),
    "name" : "hamed",
"time" : "20141105220011",
    "entity" : [ 
        "10", 
        "11"
    ]
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("546ecb07badc664b0b18ba95"),
    "name" : "ali",
    "time" : "20141105230011",
    "entity" : [ 
        "12", 
        "13"
    ]
}
```

Now I am trying to return all docs that contains (entity between 11 or 12 ) and "20141105230011"

for that I use the following code:

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
    DB db = mongoClient.getDB("test");
    DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("test");
    BasicDBObject oredrFields = new BasicDBObject();
    DBObject inOp = new BasicDBObject();
    BasicDBObject filtercol = new BasicDBObject();
    inOp.put("$in", new String[] { "10", "1" });
    filtercol.put("_id", 0);
    filtercol.put("name", 1);
    filtercol.put("entity", 1);
    filtercol.put("time", 1);
    oredrFields.put("entity", inOp);
    BasicDBObject andQuery = new BasicDBObject();
    BasicDBObject timeQuery = new BasicDBObject();
    timeQuery.put("time", new BasicDBObject("$gt","20131105241311"));
    List<BasicDBObject> obj = new ArrayList<BasicDBObject>();
    obj.add(timeQuery);
    obj.add(oredrFields);
    obj.add(filtercol);
    andQuery.put("$and", obj);
    DBCursor cursor = coll.find(andQuery);
    try {
        while (cursor.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(cursor.next());
        }
    } finally {
        cursor.close();
    }
```

But when I run it nothing returns though I have some data in the database that meet the conditions!!!!
Can anyone help? (I am totally confused)

Comment: As per I understood, you need this thing: `http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#examples`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have complicated the query with unnecessary `DBObjects`. The below code represents how to build the `DBObject` with a condition to match the documents with `entity in 11 or 12`, and `time = 20141105230011`.

```
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
    DB db = mongoClient.getDB("test");
    DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("test");

    DBObject inOp = new BasicDBObject();
    inOp.put("$in", new String[] { "11", "12" });

    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
    query.put("entity", inOp);
    query.put("time", "20141105230011");

    BasicDBObject filter = new BasicDBObject().append("_id", 0).
    append("entity", 1).append("time", 1).append("name",1);

    DBCursor cursor = coll.find(query,filter);
    try {
        while (cursor.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(cursor.next());
        }
    } finally {
        cursor.close();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot the above code works well but the only thing is I just want to return entity and name and time but not id so when I add for example this filtercol.put("time", 1); the code does not return anything !!!

Comment: To project just the required columns you need to pass the filter DBObject as the second argument to the find() method. Please check my updated answer.